# How to draw a vertical line in JPanel at a specific position?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, japplet

I am trying to design a timeline for this media playback application using a `JPanel`. In order to provide an indication of the current video frame with respect to the timeline, I need to be able to draw a vertical line at a specific x-coordinate in this `TimeLinePanel` class that extends `JPanel`. So far, I haven't had much luck with using the paint() function or overriding the `paintComponent()`. When I tried to use the paint() function in my `NewJApplet` (this class extends `JApplet`) class, the vertical line is drawn, but the `JPanel` that I'm using as the timeline disappears (the border is no longer visible). In addition, I've heard that using the `paint()` method was not preferrable. As a result, I've tried to override `paintComponent()` method in `JPanel` and I've tried calling the paintComponent method from `NewJApplet`, but it does not update `timeLinePanel1` with the vertical line.

Any help would be appreciated.

The following is the code I have so far:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package helloworld;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Justin
 */
public class NewJApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {

    /**
     * Initializes the applet NewJApplet
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */

        try {
            /*
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
            * */
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the applet */
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                    timeLinePanel1.paintComponent(timeLinePanel1.getGraphics());
                    timeLinePanel1.repaint();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the init() method to initialize the
     * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        myPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        timeLinePanel1 = new helloworld.TimeLinePanel();

        myPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout myPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(myPanel);
        myPanel.setLayout(myPanelLayout);
        myPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            myPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(myPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(timeLinePanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 600, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        myPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            myPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, myPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(timeLinePanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(myPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(0, 0, 0))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(myPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JPanel myPanel;
    private helloworld.TimeLinePanel timeLinePanel1;
    // End of variables declaration
}


/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package helloworld;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Justin
 */
public class TimeLinePanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form TimeLinePanel
     */
    public TimeLinePanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(3, 0, 1, 25);
        g.fillRect(25, 0, 1, 25);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 25, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

This is what I get when I try to run the applet. Ideally, I'd like to have a vertical line drawn at some (x,y) coordinate in the white box (`timeLinePanel1`), such as (25,0) (as indicated in the code) to get an understanding of how I can proceed with drawing vertical lines within a JPanel.

[image]

Comment: Will other components appear on to of the timeline?  If not, it is simpler to use a `BufferedImage` as the canvas, and display it on a label.  I'd guess a lot of the problems you are seeing have to do with preferred sizes and layouts.  Using an image should get around those problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call super.paintComponent in order to paint everything in your panel:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.fillRect(25, 0, 1, 25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that it's correct answer but probably you forget to set the color?

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(3, 0, 1, 25);
    g.fillRect(25, 0, 1, 25);
}
```